# PL/SQL: I have problem updating a table with data from another table

Tags: oracle, plsql

First table `ROOMDB`:

| roomnumber | rentalbalance |
| --- | --- |
| N327 | 0 |

Second table `RENTALINVOICE`:

| invoicedate | roomnumber | totaldue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/26/2021 | N327 | 2,200.00 |

My update code:

```sql
UPDATE ROOMDB
SET 
RENTALBALANCE = (SELECT TOTALDUE
                   FROM RENTALINVOICE
                  WHERE RENTALINVOICE.ROOMNUMBER=ROOMDB.ROOMNUMBER
                    AND INVOICEDATE=SYSDATE) ;
```

I need to update the `totaldue` column in `ROOMDB` with data from `RENTALINVOICE` though it successfully enters 2,200 to the `totaldue` column, AT THE SAME TIME IT ALSO WIPES OUT THE REST OF THE RECORDS on this column in `ROOMDB`.

Everytime I update it, it erases the rest of the records except the `roomnumber`  I specified. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically seem to also updates rows in table `roomdb` where there is no row in table `rentalinvoice` and therefore the column `rentalbalance` will be set to null.

Have a look a following example:

```sql
drop table a;
create table a (id number, cost number);
insert into a values (1, 1);
insert into a values (2, 2);

drop table b;
create table b (id number, cost number);
insert into b values (1, 100);

-- updates all rows in a and sets cost to null whenen there is no row in b
update a set cost = (select cost from b where a.id = b.id);
select * from a;

-- only updaes rows in a where there is a row in b
update a set cost = id;
update a set cost = (select cost from b where a.id = b.id) where exists (select 1 from b where a.id = b.id);
select * from a;
```

Comment: thanks doberkofler,, is this better?

UPDATE ROOMDB
SET 
RENTALBALANCE = (SELECT TOTALDUE FROM RENTALINVOICE WHERE INVOICEDATE=SYSDATE AND ROOMNUMBER=ROOMDB.ROOMNUMBER) WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM RENTALINVOICE WHERE INVOICEDATE=SYSDATE AND ROOMNUMBER=ROOMDB.ROOMNUMBER)
;

Comment: It looks better but the use of `sysdate` in your `update` might be problematic. I would rather use `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RENTALINVOICE WHERE INVOICEDATE=ROOMDB. INVOICEDATE AND ROOMNUMBER=ROOMDB.ROOMNUMBER) ;` and you must be careful when using sysdate as it also contains the time so often you rather only compare the date portion of a date with something like `trunc(sysdate)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute an update command like this Oracle will update all the table rows. For every row Select command will execute with these row values. If the result of select in the update does not find any record will return null. In this situation the `RENTALBALANCE` column will set null too.

```sql
(SELECT TOTALDUE
          FROM RENTALINVOICE
         where WHERE RENTALINVOICE.ROOMNUMBER = ROOMDB.ROOMNUMBER
                 AND INVOICEDATE = SYSDATE)
```

Comment: It appears that you don't know how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).